# How to clean pine wood floor (kitchen)?

Tags: kitchens, floor, cleaning, pine

[image]

I bought an older apartment with wooden floor, so I have no idea what kind of wood is it, what protection was used for it and what actually is that dirt. I was trying to clean it with soap water.
Result of "cleaned" kitchen floor.

- Something was cleanable (great)
- Yellow arrows, I was dark spot which I cleaned but I still have this stains which looks like wet
- Red arrows, I could not cleaned it at all. This mess seem to be inside of the wood

How can I clean the floor and not hurt it? I prefer solution without sanding.

Comment: Please, have addition questions to find better solution, comment it.

Comment: That looks like pine, not hardwood.  Is there any sort of finish on it now?  From the transition in the upper right hand corner of the photo it looks like it used to have varnish or poly on it that was sanded off.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the wood type. By using and cleaning, the finish was "sanded" from some parts of the floor. Therefore some mess get in to the wood (red arrows). I have heard some people were using vinegar but I found out it can also hurt the floor.

Comment: After you clean the floor as well as possible, I suggest sealing it properly. No idea what kind of sealant would be appropriate for a kitchen, but if you don't, this is just going to happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Its rubbed in oil, dirt and small particles of metal. There is no way on the planet you can get it out. Sanding deep is the only option.

You can use oxalic acid, which will bleach the wood and significantly lighten the stains. Oxalic acid is powerful stuff, so be careful.

Comment: It unfortunately appears to be unfinished wood. I would see your landlord about the flooring, as that looks more like a subfloor than a floor to me. An easy "fix" would be to get a piece of laminate/vinyl flooring cut to fit and just lay it overtop.

Comment: Tyler - if you can send me link to good youtube tutorial about how to work with acid, it would be great.

Comment: BrownRedHawk - I like the wood so nothing (excluding protection) will be laying on it :)